# In LE Privacy mode, does the address of the advertising entity change after connection is established?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

In Bluetooth Spec (CoreV5.0, Vol6, Chepter6, Section1) it is mentioned that the random private address is generated periodically by a timer handler. I could not find any mention on whether the timer should be stopped when a connection is established. So, I could not figure out whether the address should keep changing even after the connection is established. Can any one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection establishment and advertisement are two disjoint things: you can go on advertising after successful connection, even if not all devices implement that behavior.  That's probably why there is no mention of stopping the timer after successful connection.

If you are designing a device with only once concurrent connection supported, for which advertisement stops once connection is established, random address of device will not be used before disconnection and next advertisement, so you can disable timer while connected, this will make no difference.